# How to get questions which exclusively match only the specified tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, hyperlinks

How can I search for questions with certain tags and no other tags? So e.g. I want all questions with exactly the tag [java](/questions/tagged/java), and not questions that include [java](/questions/tagged/java) but also include other tags

Comment: I *think* he wants questions with exactly the tags he specifies, and no other tags. Which is kind of an odd request

Comment: Yes, questions with Java without Tomcat, Maven, Eclipse, ...

Comment: And same also with other topics...

Comment: @Marvin That would work, if you're willing to manually exclude every tag in the system. He wants `[tagA] AND [tagB] AND ![*]`

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you entered this as a feature request, and because I don't know that it's possible to do this from the main search (as opposed to the data explorer), I'm going to post this as an answer:

There are something like, what; 30k tags on SO? A great many of these are synonymous with others, and many cover fairly esoteric things. As an example, the following tags exist: [iterator](/questions/tagged/iterator) [iteration](/questions/tagged/iteration) [iterate](/questions/tagged/iterate) [iterative](/questions/tagged/iterative)

Someone might add any of those tags to a question that you would otherwise *want* to show up in your query for "only the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag". There are hundreds - no, thousands - of other examples of kinds of tags which would render the kind of queries you want to do basically worthless.

You would be better off searching for your desired tags, and leaving off ones you do not want. Prefix the tag with a minus sign to do that.

So, in the search box:

```
[discussion] -[comments]
```

Or in a URL:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion+-comments
```

Comment: If I can ask to include tags with "+"-sign, is there a sign to exclude tags in url?

Comment: Added info about excluding tags to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**The following does not *exclusively* search but it gets stuff done; getting tags you don't want out.**

---

Add the tags you don't want to your Ignored Tags list under preferences

https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/**youridhere**

The unanswered page with [java] search

[image: java only search]

Placing the blackberry tag in the ignored filter.

[image: No more research]

No more berries in sight.

[image: Only if this happened IRL]

*Of course remember to remove it from the ignored filter when you are done with it*