# How to find unanswered questions for specified tags

Tags: support

I have gone through [How to get questions which exclusively match only the specified tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119166/how-to-get-questions-which-exclusively-match-only-the-specified-tags) but could not get understand it.

Is there any URL for Stack Exchange sites, from which further information can be explored?

At the moment, I am interested in unanswered questions for following tags: [metro](/questions/tagged/metro), [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same URL format except with `/unanswered` instead of `/questions`.

To get *either* tag, use https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/metro-ui+or+windows-8.

To get *both* tags, use https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/metro-ui+windows-8 (the "and" is implicit, unlike "or").

Comment: thanks. I was looking exactly the same. 
I was not aware of /questions though. Will use extensively.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/metro+and+.net
and
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/metro 
are not working.
Can you provide slightly more information, or may be point to related link?

Comment: The `[metro]` tag doesn't exist, perhaps you want `[metro-ui]` instead. Also, you don't want to have `[and]` tag there :)

Comment: Thanks mmyers, and Chichiray